# how to obtain which submit button was clicked jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to define a rule for required fiels depending on the submit button clicked:

```
$(function() {
    $("form[name='formSim']").validate({
        rules :
            {selecedElement : {
                required : { 
                    depends : function() {
                        return $("#action").val() == "opt1";
                    }
                }
            }
    });
});
```

I have two buttons at the bottom of the form:

```
<div class="align-right">
        <button type="submit" name="action" id="action" value="opt1">Option 1</button>
        <button type="submit" name="action" id="action" value="opt2">Option 2</button>
</div>
```

the issue is that, the value $("#action").val() obtained is allways "opt1", regardless the button I click

Comment: That's because you are using the same `id="action"` on both buttons. `ID`'s are supposed to be **unique** to a specific element.

Comment: Because you wrote return $("#action").val() and it will return value of very first element with id="action".

Answer (score 1):

first of all, `id` is supposed to be a **unique** identifier. You can't have two buttons with the same id.

Secondly, two `submit` buttons make no sense, because a submit action is not connected to the buttons - the *form* is submitted, not the button, such that you even have an [`onsubmit` event for forms](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onsubmit.asp) that is independent of the button press.

What you want, instead, is to set both buttons to `type="button"` and handle their behavior differently. Something along the lines of:

```
<div class="align-right">
        <button type="button" name="action" value="opt1" onclick="handleClickOpt1()">Option 1</button>
        <button type="button" name="action" value="opt2" onclick="handleClickOpt2()">Option 2</button>
</div>
```

and then, since you're using jQuery, you can `submit` the form from within these handler functions for whatever behavior you're looking.

You should be asking a different question, however: *why* do you need two buttons that submit a form but behave differently? Why not use a checkbox to toggle between button functionalities instead?

Comment: the two buttons submit the forms to diferent html pages but certain fields are required for one case and are optional for the other

Comment: in this case, you definitely want two buttons with different handlers. You effectively have two different forms, with different outlets and different validators, so you have to handle them separately.

Answer (score 0):

This is because, [according to the specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/struct/global.html#adef-id), HTML/JS is weird when you have two elements on the page with the same ID. Try chaning `id="action"` to something different and see if that works better.